# How to use the jQuery Ajax success method from another page without re-writing the whole part?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, json

How can i use this function always but only extend the `success: function..` to my seperate callback?

global.js

```
// one time written and will be uesd 100 times without re-write the same thing.
function useEveryWhere(url, par) {
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      dataType: "json",
      url: url, //PHP call
      data: par,
      async: true,
      success : function(msg) {}            
    }); 
}
```

anotherpage1.js

```
// Here i need the success: function with different task 
ueEveryWhere(url, parameters);
```

anotherpage2.js

```
// Here i need the success: function with different task too not same as anotherpage1.js
ueEveryWhere(url, parameters);
```

How do i have that global.js success method in any other scripts too, where i have random task not all are same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [ajaxSucess](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxSuccess/) function to specify a global sucess method, and change `useEveryWhere` to accept a success function:

```
function useEveryWhere(url, par, sucess) {
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      dataType: "json",
      url: url, //PHP call
      data: par,
      async: true,
      success : sucess      
    }); 
}
```

anotherpage1.js

```
useEveryWhere(url, parameters, function() { ... });
```

anotherpage2.js

```
useEveryWhere(url, parameters, function() { ... });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Global AJAX Event Handlers with jQuery: http://api.jquery.com/category/ajax/global-ajax-event-handlers/

Just add: `$.ajaxSuccess(function () { /*code here*/ });` and every AJAX response that is a success will run the code.

Comment: I have a multi-tasking. Like index.php is crawling 2 events. And same page another instance is executing a iframe submit or trying to execute other task. Will it be also possible with this same theory?

Comment: Will it be possible to have a duplicate? Lets say 12:00:01 time-stamp, from same page i have 5 simultaneous execute. Will all the 5 will have 1 success report or 5 times?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, but these Global AJAX Event Handlers run for every AJAX event, they will not run when an iframe change's it's source, but you can pass the name of a function rather than an anonymous function so you can easily call it from other places in your code: `function my_func () { console.log('blah'); } $.ajaxSuccess(my_func);`

Comment: All five AJAX requests will fire the callback function.

Comment: OK - All five AJAX requests i need 5 separate callback dedicated towards themself instead of central one callback. Can i still do with this?

Comment: **Yes**, every AJAX request will get it's own callback that you specify in the `.ajaxSuccess()` function call. I would take a minute to read the documentation I posted.

Answer (score 0):

Use jQuery `$.Deferred` objects:

```
$.when(useEveryWhere(url, parameters)).done(function() { /* callback 1 */ });
$.when(useEveryWhere(url, parameters)).done(function() { /* callback 2 */ });
```

Comment: @Google , extremely useful also to define everytime a different error callback. Just chain the `fail()` function